# Best practice for dealing with duplicate classes in separate namespaces

Tags: c#, json, class, xna, namespaces

I'm using XNA as the framework for my game. In my `Input` class, I use XNA to get the keyboard state and detect key presses:

```
namespace MyGame.Classes
{
    public class Input : IInput
    {
        public bool DetectKey( Keys key )
        {
            if ( Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown( key ) )
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Lately I've been trying to integrate Newtonsoft.Json to manage the configuration settings for my game. In another class, I read the JSON file:

```
{
    "Settings": {
        // ...
    },
    "Controls": {
        "Keyboard": {
            "W": "Up",
            "A": "Left",
            "S": "Down",
            "D": "Right"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I cast the JSON to a strongly typed object:

```
namespace MyGame.Classes
{
    public class Config
    {
        public Settings Settings = new Settings();
        public Controls Controls = new Controls();
    }

    public class Controls
    {
        public Keyboard Keyboard = new Keyboard();
    }

    public class Keyboard
    {
        public string W = "Default";
        public string A = "Default";
        public string S = "Default";
        public string D = "Default";
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is I want to use both `Keyboard` classes (`MyGame.Classes.Keyboard` and `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keyboard`) in my `Input` class like this:

```
namespace MyGame.Classes
{
    public class Input : IInput
    {
        public bool DetectUp( Config config )
        {
            // Convert string to enum
            var key = GetKey( config.Controls.Keyboard.W );
            return DetectKey( key );
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously the compiler isn't happy about this. I've been searching for a solution, but most people that have asked about this have control over both namespaces in question. I'm not sure how to adapt any of these solutions to my situation:

- [Namespace and Class Naming Best Practice in Atypical System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713316/namespace-and-class-naming-best-practice-in-atypical-system)
- [Separate projects or multiple class files ... namespace best practice in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2231368/separate-projects-or-multiple-class-files-namespace-best-practice-in-c-sharp)
- [Identical class names in different namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717278/identical-class-names-in-different-namespaces)

I tried adding this to the top of `Input`:

```
using Keyboard = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keyboard;
using KeyboardConfig = MyGame.Classes.Keyboard;
```

This doesn't work because the compiler still tries to use `MyGame.Classes.Keyboard` to resolve every `Keyboard` in the class.

What is the best way for me to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were right, you should be using those using statement identifiers for this.

I'm guessing this isn't working either because you put the class name in the using statement and/or used the same identifier name as the class name.

Did you try something like this?

```
using kb = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

var test = kb.Keyboard.GetState(...);
```

Comment: This works. But I wasn't crazy about prefixing every usage of XNA's `Keyboard` class, so I ended up moving `MyGame.Classes.Config` and related classes to a different namespace, `MyGame.Settings`. Then I can add `using Keyboard = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Keyboard;` to my `Input` class and all is well.